# Use npm modules written in ES6 with react-scripts

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, ecmascript-5, react-scripts

In my project I need to use the npm module [ipfs-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-api) with `create-react-app`.

I can run `npm start` and run the proect.

But when I try to build the proect with `react-scripts build`, it throws the following error

> Failed to compile.
>
> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>
> `./node_modules/ipfs-api/src/utils/module-config.js:7`
>
> Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify

According to the suggestions in the provided link in eorror log, I tried using,

```
"dependencies": {
     ...
     "ipfs-api": "github:atfornes/js-ipfs-api#transpiled",
     ...
}
```

instead of `"ipfs-api": "^22.0.0",`. Although this solved error for `ipfs-api`, other dependent modules (probably installed with `ipfsapi`) kept giving same type of `Failed to minify` errors which I stopped transpiling them manually.

Is there a way to transile all the dependent node modules to es5 while before using the command `react-scripts build` ? Or any other way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually client-side or platform independent packages are compiled to ES5 on publishing. That you have this problem may suggest that the package isn't intended for client side.

As [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-api#in-a-web-browser-from-cdn) explains, the package contains a bundle for browsers that includes polyfilled Node features (streams, etc.) that are needed to run it on client side.

It's supposed to be used as a global:

```
import 'ipfs-api/dist';

ipfs(...)
```

> Is there a way to transile all the dependent node modules to es5 while before using the command react-scripts build ?

This would require to eject create-react-app configuration and configure Webpack to transpile this package properly. [This example](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api/blob/7ee17bab7e746a274ab04d5cb38fefde93550121/examples/bundle-webpack/webpack.config.js#L28-L32) from the documentation shows how Node-specific parts should be configured to bundled for browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, I'll check and get back to you

Comment: I finally decided to build the react app from scratch rather than using `create-react-app` and to eject configs. Fortunately the app was in ti initial stage

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. `create-react-app eject` provides a reasonable boilerplate project, can be better or worse than any other React+Webpack starter.